# Pagespeed Insights API for pages behind authentication

Tags: pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I am using the lighthouse API to pull pagespeed insights and recommendations and have run into an issue where when I test the page in the ui, https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights, I get results but the screen shot of the page only shows the log in page. Technically the page is available both publicly (without logging in) and behind the login though. I am afraid that the results are for the "log in page" and not the page I want to analyze.

Curious if anyone has run into the same and if there is a way past this with the API (eg: API request inclusive of user credentials, etc).

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: **You cannot do this with the Page Speed Insights API**, but you can do it running your own instances of Lighthouse using puppeteer (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse and https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer). Steep learning curve but gives you a lot of options going forward. Alternatively just log in and use developer tools > audits as that is the same engine.